# ERC-20 Token Transfer Error - Eth subtracted from contract but not added to a wallet

Tags: transactions, etherscan, rinkeby

While testing NFT contract on Rinkeby I encountered a situation where I cannot transfer eth from my contract. I had 0.01 Eth on the contract and then I called `transfer` to withdraw 0.008 Eth ([transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x80d3a014d4a2a7c3cc7a87bc82b3145af694f74f39fc6087cd1d368747feb714))

```
    function transfer(address payable _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
```

The transaction is successful, it deducts Eth from the contract but my [wallet](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x83f2e217c8b9a2ee3e1b05a5cd62317aa55cb22d) does not receive the value. Only thing that indicates any error is

> ERC-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs), Check with Sender.

But according to my understanding I should not emit this event on my own, because it is not necessary in the official tutorials, e.g. in https://solidity-by-example.org/payable/.

Might there be a problem with the fact that the contract is inherited from ERC721?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ether was transferred correctly. Most wallet don't show internal transaction and probably the wallet you are using isn't displaying a change, but the balance should reflect the change.

Etherscan believes it is a token transfer because of the function signature (`transfer(address,uint256)`). Since no `Transfer` event is emitted it shows the error *ERC-20 Token Transfer Error*.

TL;DR Function works correctly, ether is transferred.